Nikon D40 - electronic shutter activation? (Not IR remote)
For a hobby project I would like to activate my Nikon D40's shutter electronically (e.g. over a wire by a piece of external circuitry I'm building).  I cannot use the IR remote control for this as there are other infra-red lights in the area that would interfere with the timing.
I have seen several after-market "battery grip" products which feature additional shutter release buttons (so one can comfortably shoot portrait).  These grips slot into the battery compartment and use the electronic contacts seen here:

Is anyone familiar with these devices?  I need to find out the individual signals for each of the contacts in the green area on the above picture.  I did ponder just buying one of these cheap battery grips and opening it up to investigate, but I'd rather not.
I suspect the 5 circular contacts will be signals for the "shutter half-press", "shutter full-press" and perhaps selection wheel inputs.  But I have no way to know which is which as there are no markings.
I can't find any information in the manual (I guess Nikon didn't want meddlesome consumers like me messing around with it!).  Nothing online either on 3rd-party sites.
Perhaps someone here has such a battery grip for a D40 and might be able to advise me?
Further info: This is a screenshot from https://fotoexpert.pl/ of such a grip product (might not be the exact model, but it's this kind of thing)...


I couldn't find any such battery grip. Do you have a link?

I've added a link above, thanks.  Now I see some more images of these things, there seems to be another type which only has the shutter button but does not have the extra electronic contacts in the battery compartment!  Those simpler ones seem to have a cable that goes from the grip and into the D40's USB device port.  I wonder if they are using the USB "ID" pin as a shutter release?!

do you specifically want to see if you can hack your d40? or do you simply want to actuate a camera as a requirement for your overall project?

@LightBender, I want to actuate this particular camera using a signal from an external source (which I can control).  I don't actually want to modify the D40 camera body at all, I am hoping that any stimulus can be done by using modified 3rd-party connectors, cables or such.  I love my D40 and wouldn't consider butchering it for any reason at all! :)

I can find no battery grip or accessory for the D40 that connects to those pins. (The pictured grip is for the D80) All of the D40 grips I've found use IR to communicate button presses to the camera.
If even the Nikon battery grip chose not to use those pins and use IR (considering a little wire and a trio of pins is rather cheaper than a little wire, a microcontroller, a custom board, an IR diode, and a lens assembly), it is more likely that those pins are used for programming and automated testing of the camera. If so, any attempt to send arbitrary voltage through those pins might fry the extremely delicate electronics in the camera.
Assuming you absolutely want to use your D40* and are willing to accept the risk of experimenting, I recommend you ask a question over on the electronic stack exchange on the best procedures for diagnosing an unknown interface.
*A used D70s or higher will have one of the standard wired remote ports. Their respective pin outs are freely available and people have been hacking together electronic controls for them for decades. I'd recommend going new enough to get a CMOS sensor though. So D90, D300 or D3100 (or newer).

Those connectors are not described anywhere, you would need to disassemble the camera and check what they do.
Or, as the most obvious alternative, take apart a battery grip which does it!
The "Jenis MB-D40 Battery Pack with LCD for Nikon D40/D40X" (available on the website you linked) has a reasonable price of 59 PLN and it has the external shutter release button. Just open it, solder wires to the contact where the button operates (remember that there are two, since the button also detects half-press) and you are done.
If you value your time, this solution is much cheaper than any other solution involving building something that connects to those contacts inside the battery compartment. Also, very likely the shutter release has no specific contact, but it's communicated digitally, so you would need a chip for that.

There are two reasons I can't use the IR remote (I did try it).  Firstly the aforementioned IR interference (both strobing and high-intensity ambient near IR wavelengths).  Secondly, the signal from the remote is lacking in resolution.  It's one pulse every 34 ms and I need to be able to trigger the camera (set up in full manual mode with all focusing locked etc.) within about 5 ms of the triggering event which comes from my external electronics.  If the first pulse is missed from the IR remote, then the even has already been missed and it's got to be set up all over again.

@Wossname add that to the question and also add why do you expect so tight tolerance out of D40 after the button press. Typical DSLR latency after pressing shutter is 100+ ms and maybe slightly less when pre-lifting the mirror.

@Wossname see updated answer

Well, you can measure the resistance between each contact on the grip while fiddling with the buttons on the grip (so no danger for the camera at that point). I would expect the resistance to drop significantly between two of these when you half-press the shutter, and between one of these two and a third one when you full-press. The other could be just the output of incremental rotary encoders (two lines per encoder). With 5 contacts that would be ground, shutter half-press, shutter full-press, and A and B signals for a rotary encoder.
Since you do the tests on a totally passive grip, you can order a grip, check it, and return it/resell it if you can't figure our the contacts.
Otherwise, plenty of good info on IR transmitters and how to make an Arduino cosplay as any type in this video. IR transmission could be more robust than you think.
